# cab overlay on Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, menuitem

I followed so many tutorials but I think I missed something... so my problem is I want to create an Action Mode Menu like Whatsapp, Hike used it. and so I successfully created it but it's not properly overlay on my toolbar...

I already tried the below lines in my style sheet but i don't know, why the result is not reflecting as I expected

```
    <!--  It should be true otherwise action mode will not overlay toolbar -->
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>


    <!--  For Custom Action Mode Background Color/Drawable -->
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

Toolbar xml:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1E1E21"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbarTitleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/ToolbarText"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Style Sheet:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <!--  It should be true otherwise action mode will not overlay toolbar -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <!--  For Custom Action Mode Background Color/Drawable -->
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#00BFF3</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#00BFF3</item>
</style>
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>



</style>
<style name="CircularProgress" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/buttonbackground</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Actual Image:

[image: Actual Result]

Expected Result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for -

http://theopentutorials.com/examples/android/listview/android-contextual-action-bar-for-listview-item-deletion-using-actionbarsherlock/

Comment: i m implementing on recyclerView